# CISCO Meraki - Endpoint API: Get Network Traffic 'sent' and 'received' values

Tags: cisco, meraki, traffic, api

I'm currently developing a Python script with API endpoints, specifically [get_network_traffic](https://developer.cisco.com/meraki/api/#/python/api-endpoints/networks/get-organization-networks). My only question is what unit of measure is being used for the returned 'sent' and 'received' values, KB?, GB?, MB? or does this represent the number of packets sent?

Any help with this issue would be much appreciated!